# Python: Stream gzip files from s3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have files in s3 as gzip chunks, thus I have to read the data continuously and cant read random ones.  I always have to start with the first file.

For example lets say I have 3 gzip file in s3, `f1.gz`, `f2.gz`, `f3.gz`.  If I download all locally, I can do `cat * | gzip -d`.  If I do `cat f2.gz | gzip -d`, it will fail with `gzip: stdin: not in gzip format`.

How can I stream these data from s3 using python?  I saw smart-open and it has the ability to decompress gz files with

```
from smart_open import smart_open, open

with open(path, compression='.gz') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.strip())
```

Where path is the path for `f1.gz`.  This works until it hits the end of the file, where it will abort. Same thing will happen locally, if I do `cat f1.gz | gzip -d`, it will error with `gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file` when it hits the end.

Is there a way to make it stream the files continuously using python?

This one will not abort, and can iterate through `f1.gz`, `f2.gz` and `f3.gz`

```
with open(path, 'rb', compression='disable') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.strip(), end="")
```

but the output are just bytes.  I was thinking it will work by doing `python test.py | gzip -d`, with the above code but I get an error `gzip: stdin: not in gzip format`.  Is there a way to have python print using smart-open that gzip can read?

Comment: To clarify: f1.gz, f2.gz, f3.gz are not individual chunks all compressed with gzip, but a single gzip compressed file which was then split into multiple files?

Comment: yes, you are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example lets say I have 3 gzip file in s3, `f1.gz`, `f2.gz`, `f3.gz`.  If I download all locally, I can do `cat * | gzip -d`.

One idea would be to make a file object to implement this. The file object reads from one filehandle, exhausts it, reads from the next one, exhausts it, etc. This is similar to how `cat` works internally.

The handy thing about this is that it does the same thing as concatenating all of your files, without the memory use of reading in all of your files at the same time.

Once you have the combined file object wrapper, you can pass it to Python's `gzip` module to decompress the file.

Examples:

```
import gzip

class ConcatFileWrapper:
    def __init__(self, files):
        self.files = iter(files)
        self.current_file = next(self.files)
    def read(self, *args):
        ret = self.current_file.read(*args)
        if len(ret) == 0:
            # EOF
            # Optional: close self.current_file here
            # self.current_file.close()
            # Advance to next file and try again
            try:
                self.current_file = next(self.files)
            except StopIteration:
                # Out of files
                # Return an empty string
                return ret
            # Recurse and try again
            return self.read(*args)
        return ret
    def write(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

filenames = ["xaa", "xab", "xac", "xad"]
filehandles = [open(f, "rb") for f in filenames]
wrapper = ConcatFileWrapper(filehandles)

with gzip.open(wrapper) as gf:
    for line in gf:
        print(line)

# Close all files
[f.close() for f in filehandles]
```

Here's how I tested this:

I created a file to test this through the following commands.

Create a file with the contents 1 thru 1000.

```
$ seq 1 1000 > foo
```

Compress it.

```
$ gzip foo
```

Split the file. This produces four files named xaa-xad.

```
$ split -b 500 foo.gz
```

Run the above Python file on it, and it should print out 1 - 1000.

### Edit: extra remark about lazy-opening the files

If you have a huge number of files, you might want to open only one file at a time. Here's an example:

```
def open_files(filenames):
    for filename in filenames:
        # Note: this will leak file handles unless you uncomment the code above that closes the file handles again.
        yield open(filename, "rb")
```

Comment: Right, but this only works if the files are locally right? Was trying to stream the files from s3

Comment: smart_open.open() gives you a file-like object. So, you can open the S3 object file like `smart_open.open(path, 'rb', compression='disable')`, pass a list of those file-like objects to ConcatFileWrapper, which gives you a single file-like object. Then you can pass that to gzip.open(), which gives you text.

Comment: Oh right, gotcha.  I guess that works.  If I have like hundreds of file in s3 though, would that cause an issue? Having hundreds of file like object?  But I guess concatfilewrapper will only iterate one file object at a time

Comment: Because the above code uses `iter()` and `next()`, it doesn't need to be a list specifically. It can be any iterable. If you're concerned about having too many files open at once, you can write a generator that yields file handles. See edit. That way, you'll only have one file open at once. Note: If you do that, you should probably change the ConcatFileWrapper to close files after it reaches the EOF of each file. (See the comment "Optional" above.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  This looks like it will work exactly on my use case.